# How can an ASP.NET Web API method receive an object with polymorphic properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a scenario where I'm passing some data to an ASP.NET Web API method, one piece of which is a list of objects which share a base type.  So, the method accepts the POST data in a single DTO parameter, as Web API expects, like so:

```
public HttpResponseMessage SaveConfig(SaveConfigRequest req) {
    // do stuff with req
}
```

The `SaveConfigRequest` DTO has data something like this:

```
public class SaveConfigRequest {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BaseParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

`BaseParameter` is an abstract class with a couple of concrete implementations:

```
public abstract class BaseParameter {
    protected BaseParameter(ParameterType type) {
        this.Type = type;
    }
    public ParameterType Type { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// TODO: implement other parameters
public class DateParameter : BaseParameter {
    public DateParameter() : base(ParameterType.Date) {}
    public string DefaultDateFormula { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is for Web API to be able to deserialize a POST request containing a collection of parameters, so that they're deserialized into their concrete types.  I'm POSTing the data serialized as JSON.

One attempt that I've made is to set the [`TypeNameHandling` of the Json.NET formatter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#ID6RBSection) to `Auto` and adding a `$type` property in the JSON that I'm sending, but that still results in an empty collection in the method.

A second attempt has been to create a custom model binder for the `BaseParameter` type, but I think it's not getting triggered because `BaseParameter` isn't the model, just a part of it.  Perhaps I haven't configured it correctly (I've tried a `ModelBinder` attribute on `BaseParameter` and calling `configuration.BindParameter(typeof(BaseParameter), new ParameterModelBinder())` in `App_Start`).

So, my question is *what is the most straightforward way to allow part of my Web API method's model parameter to accept a collection of values of an abstract type?*

Comment: My experience is JSON is difficult to use polymorphic data structures unless you are using C# are both sides (because the .NET JSON contract serializer embeds the namespace in the JSON) and other languages do not understand that.   will you be calling the webservices with client built in C#?

Comment: You need to use the setting `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` in **deserialization** as well as serialization.  If you leave it as `TypeNameHandling.None` the `"$type"` is ignored in deserialization.

Comment: @dbc, I'm seeing it to Auto in the web API formatter config, does that not handle deserialization?

Comment: @dbc I just tried implementing a `JsonCoverter` as mentioned in the answer you linked to, but it's not getting called, when registered via the `JsonCoverter` attribute on `BaseParameter` or via `configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ParameterJsonConverter())`.  In fact, its `CanConvert` method was called for every property except the collection.

Comment: @tatmanblue the client is in the browser, not in C#, but I've tried manually adding the type annotation that Json.NET is looking for and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how you are deserializing the JSON?  It sounds like that may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @dbc I'm just deserializing directly through Web API (i.e. posting JSON to a Web API endpoint), not calling any Json.NET APIs directly.  I can put together a basic Web API site if it'd help…

Comment: Could you save yourself a lot of code and complexity by simply creating a route for each implementor? So you'd have `SaveDateConfigRequest()` and `SaveOtherConfigRequest()` etc

Comment: @timothyclifford unfortunately, it's a valid case to be passed multiple parameters of different types

Comment: @dbc in putting together an MCVE I figured out that my other attempts were conflicting with the `JsonConverter`, and just using that seemed to work (even without setting `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, having a `$type` property in the JSON skipped my `JsonConverter` for some reason).  Thanks!